# putting all the values of a particular column in the list through hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have the below pojo which contain many attributes and corresponding setters and getters

```
public class TOAAarty 
{

   protected long id;
   private long version;

   //corresponding setters and getters

   }
```

now i have fire the below query which bring all the values of id from the data base

```
  select id from  toa_arty  // so this query bring the  ids's
```

now in the similar fashion i want to rite HQL for this in hibernate to achieve the same as above query so what i have tried is  that basically there will be a method and result will be populated in list

so what i have tried is shown below please advise how to correct this

```
List<Long> stlist = HibernateUtil.getSession().createQuery("select id from TOAAarty ").list();
```

Comment: Well, you did not tell us what the problem is...

Comment: the problem is that when I execute the sql query above I get the all values of id column so similiar  query  I want to execute from HQL through hibernate and output of  HQL query I want to put in list I have written  the HQL pls let us know is it correct way